# How to use TLS 1.2 with MySql Go Drivers?

Tags: mysql, go

We have to use TLS1.2 to connect to our MySQL servers. In our java applications, we use the below JDBC URL -

```
jdbc:mysql://xxxx-001-dev.cluster-xx-2.rds.amazonaws.com/bats?**enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2**
```

I am not able to achieve similar configuration when connection to mysql in our Go application -

```
cfg1 := mysql.Config{
        User:                 "admin",
        Passwd:               "xxxxxxx",
        Net:                  "tcp",
        Addr:                 "xxxx-001-dev.cluster-xx-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306",
        DBName:               "xxxx",
        AllowNativePasswords: true,
    }

    sql.Open("mysql", cfg1.FormatDSN())
```

I tried adding below statements. But no help, it throws below error -

```
// enabledTLSProtocolsTLSv1.2
    cfg1 := mysql.Config{
        User:                 "admin",
        Passwd:               "xxxxxx",
        Net:                  "tcp",
        Addr:                 "xxxx-001-dev.cluster-xx-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306",
        DBName:               "xxxx",
        AllowNativePasswords: true,
    }

    cfg1.TLS.MinVersion = tls.VersionTLS12
    cfg1.TLS.MaxVersion = tls.VersionTLS12

    sql.Open("mysql", cfg1.FormatDSN())
```

Error -

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x1 addr=0xf8 pc=0x64ac21]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        C:/cmb-mmt/chp-schema-validation/main.go:28 +0x61
```

We are using 5.7.12 MySQLversion

Comment: Please specify complete version of mysql, share config of your mysql server, and do some investigations like reading: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/899#issuecomment-443493840

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. We are using 5.7.12 MySQL server.

Comment: `cfg1.TLS` is nil, you never assigned a config value.

Comment: There should/(can?) be some lines in the config about configuring TLS security, like [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html#encrypted-connection-supported-protocols:~:text=SHOW%20GLOBAL%20VARIABLES%20LIKE%20%27tls_version%27%3B)  , and how do not know how many changes there are between 5.7.12 and the latest 5.7 (5.7.41?) that are involved in that subject. this is a link to the release notes for [5.7.12](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-12.html) from **2016-04-11**, and on the left you can check the newer version .....

Comment: Wow, that more than 5 years ago, and you are concerned about a secure connection to your server ? 

Comment: Thanks @JimB - How do you suggest I do that?

Comment: Do what, assign a value to TLS, like `cfg1.TLS = ...`? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve, since the default `tls.Config` will use a minimum version of 1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solved the issue. And I'm able to connect to MySQL successfully.

```
cfg1 := mysql.Config{
        User:                 cfg.Db.Dev.User,
        Passwd:               cfg.Db.Dev.Pass,
        Net:                  "tcp",
        Addr:                 "cxx-cxxx-auroramysql-001-dev.xxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306",
        DBName:               "xxxx",
        AllowNativePasswords: true,
        TLSConfig:            "skip-verify",
        TLS:                  &tls.Config{MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12, MaxVersion: tls.VersionTLS12},
    }
```